# Wordpress wrapped added a span tag to every single p tag

Tags: custom-post-types, php, functions

I have a site with hundreds of posts. For no apparent reason, Wordpress added an extra **span** tag inside every single **p** element. It also gave every single text element a class to correlate with its position in the hierarchy, so class="p2" for the second paragraph.

I didn't ask for this, and certainly didn't elect to have this happen. The majority of the posts have not been edited/saved in a while, so I don't think it was any of my doing.

The only thing that stands out was to upgrade Wordpress to 5.2.4.

Any ideas what could have gone wrong, and how to revert the changes?

Comment: If the posts haven't been saved or updated recently then what's inserting the `span` elements? My own site runs 5.2.4 and this doesn't happen, this sounds like the work of a plugin, something that could be used to implement medium style commenting/highlighting

Comment: In my experience, this comes from pasting from non-plain-text sources. For example, if you've pasted your text from Word, or an email, or a dozen other sources - not just plain text from Notepad or a similar program. The spans are added when you first paste the text into the editor, not later on when any updates happen.

Comment: @WebElaine This was my hunch, too.